# Bitwise Left Shift operator

Tags: php, bit

```
$a = 23;
$res = $a << 4 
print($res);
```

For the code snippet pasted above, the output is 368. How is it being calculated?

I expected 92.

a is 23

a in base 2 is 10111

so a in 8 bits is 00010111

Left shift 4 is 01110000

It is - 92

Can some body explain me ?

Comment: Why did you expect 92? `<<` != `*`

Comment: Practically, each shift to the left is equal to a multiplication with two. Since you're shifting four bits that 4  such multiplications or 4^2 which is 16. 23 * 16 is equal to 368.

Comment: Biswise shift != multiplying

Comment: Perhaps you should read into it first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/what-are-bitwise-shift-bit-shift-operators-and-how-do-they-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why it is returning **368** because `$a << $b` Shift the bits of `$a $b` steps to the **left**

**23**

```
256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1
 X   X   X  X  1 0 1 1 1
```

after `$a << 4`

**368**

```
256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1
 1   0   1  1  1 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: why did you go for 9 bytes ? why we can try with 8 bytes ? I did the same, but I stopped in 8 bytes. So it was . 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1
 X   X  X 1  0 1 1 1

Comment: @IyathuraiIyngaran Your 9th bit is 1, you can not neglect it.

Comment: @akshaypjoshi, got it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check [bitwise](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) operator manual here

Convert `23` in binary and it is `10111` and when you perform shift left bitwise operator, its value will be `101110000` and when you convert it to decimal it becomes `368`.